# Getting memory location instead of value

Tags: python, memory

I have a node class which has a "symbol" attribute, which is a string.  I pass this value into a method which eventually saves it as the key in a dictionary, but otherwise does not access the value until then.

after accessing node.symbol, I print the value

trans char: '1'

I then pass it into another function as the only parameter.  In that method, I immediately print the symbol using:

```
print(symbol)
```

But it prints:

<pa3.RegEx object at 0x000001D2EFDC4640>

I would like to access the value which should be a string "1" instead of this memory location.
I know this has probably been asked many times before, but I don't know what to call this problem

```
class node:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.symbol = None  #will be a ch in alphabet, (), ~, *, or |
        self.data = data

    def get_symbol(self):
        return self.symbol`

class RegEX
    def Convert(self, nod, NFA_stack): 
        trans_char = node.get_symbol(nod)
        print("type:", type(trans_char))
        print("trans char:", trans_char, "\n")

        if nod.left == None and nod.right == None:
            print("passing trans_char into method")
            NFA = self.Generate_NFA(trans_char) 
            NFA_stack.append(NFA)
     def Generate_NFA(symbol, leftNFA = None, rightNFA = None): #NFA's are dictionaries, symbol is | or ~

        print("in new method")
        print("symbol: ", symbol)
```

In this method, trans_char is recognized as a string with a value of '1', but after passing trans_char into that other method, it becomes some memory address of the class.  The problem is that I need to use this as a value in a dictionary, not just print it.

Comment: If you print an object, you will get result of calling its \_\_str\_\_() or  \_\_repr\_\_() function, if it has one, or the default which you are seeing. You can override one of those, or if you want to print a specific value from "symbol", just print that instead. For example, print (symbol.value)

Comment: I've tried that, but for some reason it keeps becoming that address.  I'm trying to pass the value into a dictionary, but because it's a class object I can't do anything with it.

Comment: I can only give general pointers, if you don't post a reproduction.

Comment: sorry, I added it to the original post because I don't know how to add code to comments.  I really appreciate the help by the way

Comment: If I copy paste that and run it, node is not defined. "builtins.NameError: name 'node' is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument in method is reserved for the class object itself, so `Generate_NFA(symbol,...)` makes Python think that `symbol` is the object of the RegEx class that the method is called for it.

Editing your function definition to the below should fix the problem:

```
def Generate_NFA(self, symbol, leftNFA = None, rightNFA = None):
```